# Laravel Eloquent: preserve index's AUTO_INCREMENT on record deletion

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Suppose I have a table with records. `id` is `UNIQUE` with `AUTO_INCREMENT` enabled:

```
id | username
-------------
1  | John
2  | Doe
3  | Sam
4  | Waters
```

When I delete the last record, `AUTO_INCREMENT` falls back to 4. I need it to stay at 5 still.

I know I can alter the table manually after deletion. However I'm asking if Laravel Eloquent already provides this functionality.

Comment: I think you'd better  add another column to do this. Besides, there are some concurrent problems need to be noticed...

Comment: My table is not updated frequently; concurrency problems should not occur. What do you mean by another column? :thinking: